# Что означает символ звёздочка в HTML атрибуте?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите разобраться, со Frontend частью очень плохо знаком, в коде JS встретил следующую конструкцию
 `var dynamicIndex = $('form[action*="DeviationsDynamic"]');`

Что значит символ звездочки(`action*`) в данном случаи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[attr*=value]` - обозначает элемент с именем атрибута `attr` чьё значение содержит по крайней мере одно вхождение строки `"value"` как подстроки.

```
/* Все ссылки содержащие слово "example" в url будут иметь серый фон */
a[href*="example"] { background-color: #CCCCCC; }
```